# TS - Make this the generic type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to make "this" the generic type of the object?
So, I have a following structure:

```
const obj = {
  fn1: () => number,
  fn2: (arg: number) => string,
  fn3 (arg: string) => null
}
```

I want to type obj such that the functions params depend on each other:

```
export type Queries<T extends Q> = {
  fn: () => any
  decoder: (arg: ReturnType<T['fn']>) => any
  transformationFn: (args: ReturnType<T['decoder']>) => any
}
```

Where Q is

```
type Q = {
  fn: () => Promise<any>
  decoder: (...args: any[]) => any
  transformationFn: (...args: any[]) => any
}
```

now, if i use the following type signature:

```
const obj1: Queries
```

I would need to pass in a generic. But I can't pass in itself hence my question

Comment: `this` is an instance, it is not a type. So you have to declare the correct type. Why not consider using classes and composition?

Comment: yes i know, apologies, should have been more clear that i thought of it as pseudo code.

how would classes/compositions help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for *type argument inference*. To get that, I think you'll need a do-nothing function:

```typescript
interface Queries<EncodedType, DecodedType, TransformedType> {
    fn: () => EncodedType;
    decoder: (arg: EncodedType) => DecodedType;
    transformationFn: (arg: DecodedType) => TransformedType;
};

function makeQueries<EncodedType, DecodedType, TransformedType>(queries: Queries<EncodedType, DecodedType, TransformedType>) {
    return queries;
}

// Works, because the types match
const good = makeQueries({
    fn: () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    decoder: (arg: number) => String(arg),
    transformationFn: (arg: string) => null,
});

// Error as desired, because they don't match
const bad = makeQueries({
    fn: () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    decoder: (arg: number) => arg,
    // ^−−− Type '(arg: number) => number' is not assignable to type '(arg: number) => string'.
    transformationFn: (arg: string) => null,
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QMlls+U7Gx+Ch8zWC4WijHJY3WS0APUASESt3jcZB+yvIIUi6D66vQP3IYCAkAkSEO53OEBwF4E74kZBgDtd5JVvtiwwybXjXV+3EK5erFVRGLqhzr5C76UDw3G01BIA)

Comment: nice! it's something along those lines i'm looking for. so there is no way other than actually creating a "do-nothing" function?

perhaps something with type guards?

Comment: @Martin - I don't think there is. This is one of the weird things about TypeScript (IMHO). Occasionally, the only way you can do something is to have a function involved so you have a means of doing type argument inference. I remember remarking on this to one of the top TypeScript contributors here and saying something like "it would be nice if some kind of type-only function-like-thing were added so we could avoid this" and they said it might be nice, but since we have functions it's not likely to get prioritized any time soon... :-)

Comment: hmm interesting. thanks for the elaborative answer. picking yours

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is possible. But it's simpler and perhaps more idiomatic to use the relevant types as generic arguments directly:

```
export type Queries<FnReturnType, DecoderReturnType> = {
  fn: () => FnReturnType
  decoder: (arg: FnReturnType) => DecoderReturnType
  transformationFn: (args: DecoderReturnType) => any
}
```

Or even more idiomatically and easier to read, as an interface:

```
export interface Queries<FnReturnType, DecoderReturnType> {
  fn(): FnReturnType
  decoder(arg: FnReturnType): DecoderReturnType
  transformationFn(args: DecoderReturnType): any
}
```

Comment: i thought about this solution but hoped there was a more generic way of doing it